# I wonder why range slice is not working properly in python

Tags: python

I made code as follows to execute binary search in sorted list for my study.
Code to find which number of values 'x' are in the list 'ss'.
Problem is, it should execute as reducing range of list, but it doesn't work.

```
def bin_search(ss, x):
    return bin_search_range( ss, x, range(len(ss)) )

def bin_search_range(ss, x, r):
    print(r)
    print("len(r)", len(r))
    if len(r) > 0:
      mid = ((r.start) + (r.stop)) // 2       
      print("start", r.start)
      print("stop", r.stop)
      print("mid", mid)
      print("x", x," ss[mid]", ss[mid])  
      if x == ss[mid]:
        print("----[x = ss[mid]----")
        return print("answer", mid)
      elif x < ss[mid]:    
        print("----[x < ss[mid]]----")
        return bin_search_range(ss, x, r[:mid])
      else:                
        print("----[x > ss[mid]]----")
        return bin_search_range(ss, x, r[mid+1:])

    else: # len(r) == 0
      return None

#Except "return print("answer", mid)", I just wrote down the rest of the output to know the progress.
```

In the manner of recursion, I repeated slicing the list through mid(which is median of list).
Until the median and 'x' match.

Below median, in other words left of median. There was no problem finding the value in.
There was a problem when finding the value on the right side of the median.

Below are the results of the execution of **bin_search ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 5)**.

```
[Execution Result]
bin_search ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 5)
range(0, 7)
len(r) 7
start 0
stop 7
mid 3
x 5  ss[mid] 4
----[x > ss[mid]]----
range(4, 7)
len(r) 3
start 4
stop 7
mid 5
x 5  ss[mid] 6
----[x < ss[mid]]----
range(4, 7)
len(r) 3
start 4
stop 7
mid 5
x 5  ss[mid] 6
.
.
.
#RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Since x = 5, ss[mid] = 6, shouldn't the range of range be reduced to (4,5)?
Just like my prediction below

```
[Expected Result]
range(0, 7)
len(r) 7
start 0
stop 7
mid 3
x 5  ss[mid] 4
----[x > ss[mid]]----
range(4, 7)
len(r) 3
start 4
stop 7
mid 5
x 5  ss[mid] 6
----[x < ss[mid]]----
range(4, 5)
len(r) 3
start 4
stop 5
mid 4
x 5  ss[mid] 5
----[x = ss[mid]----
answer 4
```

Besides, when len(r) becomes 0, I thought I would print None, but I can't get any output.
Doesn't None print out when all the runs are over? I thought None would be printed because there was no range to search anymore, but I don't know why it couldn't be printed.

No matter how hard I think about it, I don't know if there's a problem with the code. If you know anything about it, I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: I don't think ``r[mid+1:]`` is correct – it will remove ``mid+1`` items from the range, but it should actually put the lower bound to ``mid+1``. That is only correct for the first step. Creating a new range ``range(mid+1, r.stop)`` instead of slicing should work. Alternatively, ``r[mid+1-r.start:]`` might be correct (maybe off-by-one). FWIW, I would recommend to explicitly pass around the ``start``/``stop`` instead of misusing a ``range``.

Comment: I don't get why you think ``None`` should be printed. The code returns ``None``, it does not seem to have any path to print it.

Comment: to make sure result is printed, do ````print(bin_search ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 5))````. I think your problem is you do not appreciate python index start with 0, so you are confusing yourself in working with data and index that differ by 1.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for your advice. if you don't mind, Can you tell me why [mid+1:] is removed?
Isn't range [A:B] returning A through B-1? Then, if range [mid+1], isn't it right to return it from mid+1? I don't know why it's being removed.
I'm sorry about Question part about None. I was completely mistaken.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi And I made a mistake when I first posted the question, so I just slightly corrected it.

If you run the code I created, everything will be output normally except when x is 5 in the list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]. 
Only one case is when x is greater than mid at first and then less than mid at range... Is it the same problem that mid+1 you're talking about isn't the right code?

And I was told to stop misusing range and use start/stop, can you explain how to approach it?

I'm sorry to bother you.

Comment: @BingWang Thanks for the advice, but I don't think i am confusing about python index starting with 0.
Also thank you for tell me about print. I don't know why I forgot to using it.

Comment: The slice ``[A:B]`` takes everything after the ``A``'th *position*.  Say you have ``r = range(8)``. The ``mid`` is 4 and do ``r[4:]`` once that will discard the first 4 elements -> ``r = range(4, 8)``. Now its ``mid`` is at the *value* ``(4 + 8) // 2 == 6`` – that's at the *position ``2``* of the range, but ``r[6:]`` will discard everything before *position ``6``*. You would have to do ``r[r.index(6):]`` to be correct. (1-offset omitted for terseness.)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I know why it's wrong and I'm not sure, but I think I know how to fix it. Thank you for your explanation!